# Функция возвращает два значения, а в главной функции я хочу красиво вывести эти два значения

Tags: python

Скажите, пожалуйста, если моя функция возвращает **два** значения, а в главной функции я хочу красиво `вывести эти два значения без скобок, через "-" и слово не в кавычках`, как мне записать message.

```
LINE = "William Shakespeare was an English poet, playwright and actor of the Renaissance era."

def finding_the_last_i_word(LINE):
    initial_list = LINE.split()
    without_i_list = list()
    for word in initial_list:
           if 'f' in word:
               without_i_list.append(word)
    last_i_word = without_i_list[-1]
    ordinal_numeral = initial_list.index(last_i_word) + 1
    return last_i_word, ordinal_numeral

def main():
    message = "Последнее слово, содержащее букву 'f' и его порядковый номер: {}".format(finding_the_last_i_word(LINE))
    print(LINE, '\n', message)

main()
```

Comment: Замените строку `message = "Последнее слово, содержащее букву 'f' и его порядковый номер: {}".format(finding_the_last_i_word(LINE))` на строку `message = "Последнее слово, содержащее букву 'f' и его порядковый номер: {}-{}".format(*finding_the_last_i_word(LINE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде всё понятно?

```
def main():
   some_value, num_value = finding_the_last_i_word(LINE)
   message = f"Последнее слово, содержащее букву 'f' и его порядковый номер: {some_value}, {num_value}" #с f"{что-то}" меньше кода, да и удобнее читать
   print(LINE, '\n', message)
```

И как правило хорошего тона вместо этого:

```
main()
```

Пишите так:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main() #или всё что угодно
```

Или как советует @S. Nick, можно и так, если вы не планируете использовать полученные переменные, то его метод более грамотный:

```
message = "Последнее слово, содержащее букву 'f' и его порядковый номер: {}-{}".format(*finding_the_last_i_word(LINE))
```

Comment: Это не "правило хорошего тона". Это позволяет как выполнять файл отдельно и импортировать его в другие скрипты без выполнения кода в main(). [Подробности](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/5308259).

Comment: @Эникейщик, разве так не красивее? Да, и проще понять откуда стартовать...

Comment: Я не совсем понял ваш комментарий? Что должно быть красивее? Эту строчку пишут не потому что это "правило хорошего тона" и так красивее, а потому что она выполняет определенную функцию.

Comment: согласен, но как по мне это выполняет оба пункта

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое улучшение (хоть и не спрашивали).

Лучше искать слова с конца текста. Тогда не нужно пробегать через весь текст, а достаточно найти первое совпадение (представьте, что на вход подали "Гамлета"):

```
def finding_the_last_i_word(LINE):
    initial_list = LINE.split()
    number_of_words = len(initial_list)
    for index in range(number_of_words-1, 0, -1):
           if 'f' in initial_list[index]:
               return initial_list[index], index+1
    return None, None # нет таких слов
```

И еще. Так делать нельзя:

```
ordinal_numeral = initial_list.index(last_i_word) + 1
```

`index()` возвращает индекс **первого** найденного элемента. Замените в тексте *an English poet* на *a poet of England* и получите неверный результат.